# What is a "live object" in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

In the Kubernetes documentation, there is [a section](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/) called "Working with Kubernetes Objects".

We are given an [example command](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/object-management/#examples-2) which allows you to:

> Process all object configuration files in the configs directory, and create or patch the live objects.

What makes an object a "live" object?

The term "Live object" is not in the glossary, but I know that an object is a persistent entity which is a record of intent.

So I would presume that some object is live if it exists in production (i.e. the intention has been realised). An object which is not live has not been realised yet. It does not exist. I want to check this understanding is correct though.

Comment: Did you read the first part of that section: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/declarative-config/#overview

Comment: Thanks. It states that live configurations contain live configuration values "as observed by the Kubernetes cluster". Live configuration values change. Therefore a live _object_ is an actual, changing object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Declarative Management of Kubernetes Objects Using Configuration Files - Overview](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/declarative-config/#overview):

> **live object configuration / live configuration**: The live configuration values of an object, as observed by the Kubernetes cluster. These are kept in the Kubernetes cluster storage, typically etcd.

In other words, they are talking about object (Kubernetes resources) that exists in the cluster. (Objects already created e.g. from configuration files).